# circular motion and angle

Tags: python, algorithm

I'm trying to make program(ai) to determine circular action of vehicle.
I have data of current vehicle's speed and heading. after user provide desire angle and radius, vehicle will start tile to turn and do circular drive. In this step how can I calculate radius of formed circle? I wnat to compare given and created radius.

Comment: I'd suggest starting with the formula for centripetal acceleration, plugging in the parameters you know (from the user inputs, and the performance characteristics of the vehicle you're simulating) and solving for whatever parameters are left.

Comment: Blckknght shows the right way.  Calculate the acceleration (vector difference in velocity)/time_step, divide it into the component parallel to the  average velocity, and the component perpendicular to the average velocity.  The perpendicular component is centripetal acceleration, which you can use with the average velocity to calculate the radius of curvature.

Answer (score 0):

It's a bit hard to give an answer unless you show some code (such as how user data is inputed, how the vehicle moves, and the data formatting of the current speed and heading).

Here is a suggestion, if you have the heading *and* position, you can find the radius by computing the distance between the two points whos' heading are opposite of each other.  Next, take the distance and cut it in half (thus giving you a radius).  This is assuming you have a position coordinate to work with.

If you don't have a position value (or can't get one), this problem becomes harder to solve and would require some calculus.  If that is the case, this question would be better suited for the [Mathematics Stack Exchange](http://math.stackexchange.com); at least until you provide us some code to help you with.